# How can I convert DateTime to String in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have to display date in `MMM dd,YYYY` format.

```
var performancereviews = from pr in db.PerformanceReviews
                                         .Include(a => a.ReviewedByEmployee)
                                 select new PerformanceReviewsDTO
                                 {
                                     ReviewDate=pr.ReviewDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"),
                                     EmployeeName=pr.ReviewedByEmployee.Name,
                                     JobTitle=pr.ReviewedByEmployee.JobTitle,
                                     ReviewerComments=pr.CommentsByReviewer,
                                     EmployeeComments=pr.CommentsByEmployee
                                 };
```

Here is error message that i  am getting

> ExceptionMessage: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>       ExceptionType:
>       System.NotSupportedException

When i apply `ToString` on `pr.ReviewDate` I get errors.

Kindly guide me with proper solution how can I accomplish this.  I know in normal C# coding there are several options available but in Linq how can we do it.

Comment: Generally display formatting is performed in *display* logic, not when querying data.  What is the type of `PerformanceReviewsDTO.ReviewDate`?  What error does this code give you?

Comment: @David I am aware of type if am storing string type value then definitly it should be string and it is string  here is error   ExceptionMessage:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
ExceptionType:
System.NotSupportedException

Comment: Why someone downvoted,kindly don't forget to give comments while downvoting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening because LINQ to Entities is trying to convert the expression tree into a SQL query, and while `.ToString()` *can* be translated into SQL, `.ToString(string)` *can not*.  (SQL doesn't have the same concepts of string formatting.)

To resolve this, don't perform the formatting in the query, perform it in the display logic.  Keep the query as simple as possible:

```
select new PerformanceReviewsDTO
{
    ReviewDate=pr.ReviewDate,
    EmployeeName=pr.ReviewedByEmployee.Name,
    JobTitle=pr.ReviewedByEmployee.JobTitle,
    ReviewerComments=pr.CommentsByReviewer,
    EmployeeComments=pr.CommentsByEmployee
}
```

In this case `PerformanceReviewsDTO.ReviewDate` is still a `DateTime` value.  It's not formatting the data, just carrying it.  (Like a DTO should.)

Then when you *display* the value, perform the formatting.  For example, is this being used in an MVC view?:

```
@Model.ReviewDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy")
```

You might even just add a simple property to `PerformanceReviewsDTO` for the formatted display:

```
public string FormattedReviewDate
{
    get { return ReviewDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"); }
}
```

Then whatever is binding to properties on the DTO can just bind to that (assuming it's a one-way binding in this case).

Comment: Thank you David for answering I have returing data from a Web Api and in Web Api I have only this place to convert it to proper format needed in my view for a mobile application.You can see I am using DTO(Data Transfer Objects) already I am looking for Haedrian solution figuring out how to do it.

Comment: @ProgrammingNinja: My last suggestion of adding a property to the DTO should satisfy that requirement.  When the WebAPI serialization occurs, it should serialize the `FormattedReviewDate` property as well as the `ReviewDate` property.  (If the naming is important, you can change them to something like `ReviewDate` and `PersistedReviewDate` respectively, so consuming code doesn't have to change.)  As for the other posted answer, pay attention to the comments.  It could "work" but could also have drastic side-effects.

Comment: Great Answer Thank you for taking time to address my problem.

Comment: however, there is an issue if need to filter by a string from the client, e.g. by 'Oct' ))

Answer (score 2):

The way I generally solve this problem is by first just getting the data and then selecting it in memory'.

```
var performancereviews = from pr in db.PerformanceReviews
                                      .Include(a => a.ReviewedByEmployee)
                                      .ToArray()
                                      .Select( ....);
```

By putting `ToArray` (or to List or whatever) it'll finish the sql query part and then do the rest from the collection in memory - which should be fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that materializing the entire collection into memory could easily have negative performance impacts, if the system isn't *currently* materializing the whole thing (which we can't tell from the posted code).

Comment: This results in none of the other work done in the `Select` being performed on the database, in particular the limitations as to what columns are returned.

Comment: Have an up vote, because sometimes this IS A SENSIBLE APPROACH, simply because you might not have control of the display logic, or your specs may be forcing you to do it this way (As I have just had to do).  I didn't like doing it, but I had little choice in the matter.

Comment: For the record however, if you can do it in the Display Logic, I'm totally for that, but there's no reason why your answer should have been in Negative Figures IMHO.