# Date formatting from model is not working for datatype date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, date, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have on e query where I need to format date in MM/dd/YYYY format but it is but working

I have tried query as

```
var query = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
join r in db.Registrations on sr.RegistrationId equals r.RegistrationId
join cc in db.Campus on r.CampusId equals cc.CampusId
join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
from tc in db.TutorClasses.Where(t => t.ClassId == sr.ClassId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from srt in db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(s => s.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.StudentRequestId == srt.StudentRequestId && t.TutorId == registrationid).DefaultIfEmpty()
from r1 in db.Registrations.Where(t => t.RegistrationId == tsr.TutorId).DefaultIfEmpty()
where tc.RegistrationId == registrationid
orderby sr.CreatedOn descending
select new
{   
StatusId = tsr.StatusId == null ? 1 : tsr.StatusId,
Time = db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId)
.Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString() + "-" + p.ToTime +" " +p.Date+ "<br/>"),

}).ToList().GroupBy(p => new { p.StudentRequestId }).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Here at down you can see the time where p.date is there currently it is showing format as YYYY/MM/dd format but I want it to shown MM/dd/YYYY format

On Model side I had tried doing as

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

but still not working

On controller side I had tried converting to format like below

```
Time = db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).
 Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString() + "-" + p.ToTime + " " + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) + "<br/>")
```

but in this case it is giving error as

**Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

I had also made use of converting to as enumerable

```
 var model = query.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TutorDashboard
{
Name = x.Name,
Phone = x.Phone,
Email = x.Email,
ProfilePicture = x.ProfilePicture,
TutorReviewRequestID = x.TutorReviewRequestID,
StudentRequestId = x.StudentRequestId,
RegistrationId = x.RegistrationId,
Location = x.Location,
PaymentMethod = x.PaymentMethod,
CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
AcceptedOn = x.AcceptedOn,
ClassName = x.ClassName,
CampusName = x.CampusName,
StripeId = x.StripeId,
AvailableMonth = Month,
AvailableYear = Year,
StatusId = x.StatusId == null ? 1 : x.StatusId,
Time = string.Join("", x.Time),
}).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
```

Comment: Can you confirm that it is populating the Model with the correct date value (just not displaying it correctly)?  If so, don't change your LINQ query, you should be persisting a date in the DB and returning a date type.

Comment: How are you displaying your model's `Date` property in the View?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

to this:

```
p.Dated.HasValue? ((DateTime)p.Dated).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query is translated into SQL statements, and thus there are limitations to writing LINQ. Type conversations are included in those limitations.

However, you can do formatting elsewhere too like in View.

```
@Model.Date.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY");
```

If you don't want to bother, you can set your Culture to `enUS` and use `.ToShortDateString()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use `ToString("format_string")` method from LINQ to Entities query, you need to materialize into `IEnumerable` object first with `AsEnumerable()` method:

```
var time = db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId)
           .AsEnumerable() // insert this method
           .Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString() + "-" + p.ToTime + " " + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) + "<br/>");
```

Then, pass `IEnumerable<string>` result to anonymous type part of second query:

```
var query = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
join r in db.Registrations on sr.RegistrationId equals r.RegistrationId
join cc in db.Campus on r.CampusId equals cc.CampusId
join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
from tc in db.TutorClasses.Where(t => t.ClassId == sr.ClassId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from srt in db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(s => s.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.StudentRequestId == srt.StudentRequestId && t.TutorId == registrationid).DefaultIfEmpty()
from r1 in db.Registrations.Where(t => t.RegistrationId == tsr.TutorId).DefaultIfEmpty()
where tc.RegistrationId == registrationid
orderby sr.CreatedOn descending
select new
{   
    ...
    Time = time,
    ...
}).ToList().GroupBy(p => new { p.StudentRequestId }).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

If you have large amount of stored data, besides materialization you can use either view formatting or using separate string property to display formatted date:

```
@* Display in view *@
@Model.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

// using string property in viewmodel class for formatted DateTime
public string FormattedDate 
{
    get { return Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
}
```

NB: Entity Framework's LINQ to Entities tries to convert all query methods to SQL statements, currently `ToString("format_string")` has no SQL statement equivalent associated to that method unlike `ToString()` has (similar to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(n), @Date)`).

Similar issue:

[How can I convert DateTime to String in Linq Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146606/how-can-i-convert-datetime-to-string-in-linq-query)

Comment: Look to my query I am also binding variable like TO and FROM with date. So I can not format that on view side

Comment: Well, you can still use `AsEnumerable` as said on first solution, but if your LINQ to Entities query returns very large amount of rows then storing them in memory as `IEnumerable`, consider to reduce performance issue.

Comment: well i had used that also , please review my updated question, but I can not use conversion over there as only date is not coming over there. The format I am getting is like 
1.30 AM-3.00 AM   01/06/2018
1.30 AM-4.30 AM   01/07/2018